# Looking for an example which shows the difference between @ and * in bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

`x=('hello world' "HELLO")`

Both `${#x[*]}` and `${#x[@]}` print the same output.

I understand the difference between `$@` and `$*` but I am interested to see the difference without command line arguments.

Comment: `${#...}` doesn't subject the contents of the array to further shell expansion, so those two expressions *are* identical.

Answer (score 0):

Always use @ expansion unless you have reason to use *. @ was added to work around a problem.

The two don't ALWAYS expand the same. The troubles involving* start with spaces and other shell metacharacters (quotes in particular, but $ and more as well).

The * leaves the metacharacters open for the shell to process them again, which is usually bad if you went out of your way to get them into the array. The @ protects them by expanding each array element as if it was a separately quoted value, leaving all metacharacters intact.